# Execute a function to interact with user and then pop a page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm here in the docs trying to find a way to do the following:

The user'll be on a form page, and when he goes back i need to do a verification like `"are you sure you want to discard you alterations?"` and when he click yes or no it'll execute a function and then leave the page.

I know i can use a `Platform.registerBackButtonAction()` to check when he clicks the hardware back button, but how can i do the same for the NavControll back button on the header?

I can use NavGuards and it's automatically implemented on the NavControll back button, but it leaves the page and THEN executes the function.

So the flow of what i need to do is:

`enter page >> write something on any input >> if it tries to leave the page open the check alert >> on clicking 'yes' it leaves the page`

Here is a piece of code of what i'm doing:

```
ionViewCanLeave() {
    let a = this.alerts.create({
        title: "Confirmation message?",
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Nop',
            handler: () => {
                this.navCtrl.pop();
            }
        }, {
            text: 'Yes',
            handler: () => {
                this.salvarDescricao();
            }
        }]
    });

    if (this.changes != undefined && this.changes!= '') { //just a check i do, if the user doesn't change anything i don't need to ask
        a.present();
    } else {
        this.navCtrl.pop(); //if nothing changes it pops twice
    }
}
```

So how can i achieve this? How to prevent the user from leaving the view, executing a code and depending on the results it leaves?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
public someMethod(): void {
    // in this method the input was modified
    // ...
    this.showAlertMessage = true;
}

ionViewCanLeave() {
    if(this.showAlertMessage) {
        let alertPopup = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Exit',
            message: '¿Are you sure?',
            buttons: [{
                    text: 'Exit',
                    handler: () => {
                        alertPopup.dismiss().then(() => {
                            this.exitPage();
                        });         
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Stay',
                    handler: () => {
                        // need to do something if the user stays?
                    }
                }]
        });

        // Show the alert
        alertPopup.present();

        // Return false to avoid the page to be popped up
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private exitPage() {
    this.showAlertMessage = false;
    this.navCtrl.pop();
}
```

I'm assuming the page was pushed. If this page was set as root, you can replace the line `this.navCtrl.pop();` by `this.navCtrl.setRoot(someOtherPage);`

Comment: This worked very well. Didn't know it was more like a question than an affirmation, like `ion view can leave?` and returning false would stop it from leaving. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/), you can implement like this

```
ionViewCanEnter(): boolean{
   // here we can either return true or false
   // depending on if we want to leave this view
   if(isValid(randomValue)){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```